# using Ethereum without any gas or coins usage for transactions

Tags: dapps

I am new to Ethereum.

We are planning to use Ethereum for building an application where-in we don't want the users to buy and use Ether's. We want the user's to safely store and retrieve / share the information in the Ethereum Blockchain.

I have explored on the basics of Gas and their reduction for each step of execution in the SmartContract.

However, I would like to know if I can use the platform without requiring the user's to buy Ether and submit their data for sharing / storage. Also note that, I am planning to try out building an application that uses 0 Gas and 0 GasPrice.

I have read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29862/how-to-execute-smart-contract-code-without-gas-or-ether) question to be relevant, but the user wants to run in the local system, where as I would like to have it hosted in Ethereum network and make it available for public use.

Comment: One option is to use a Plasma side chain.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I would like to know if I can use the platform without requiring the user's to buy Ether and submit their data for sharing / storage. Also note that, I am planning to try out building an application that uses 0 Gas and 0 GasPrice.

You can't use the benefits of the ecosystem without contributing back. If your transaction changes the state of the blockchain, there will be an associated cost, unless you happen to have a large enough hash rate under your control, in which case you can mine your own/your user's transactions with a 0 Wei gasprice.

Alternatively, you can run a private ethereum network.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EIP-1077](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1077). You can let users sign messages and execute them on their behalf. Then you (or whoever executes) would pay for the gas and the users don’t have to pay for it.

You would need to implement the functionality in a smart contract depending on your app you may also need to implement or provide key management for the users.